# Instruct Jackson to serialize from given method

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson library vs 2.6.3. I would like to define the serialization method inside a class and I would like to instruct Jackson to call this method when an object is serialized.

E.g.

```
public interface AClass {

  default String toJSON(){
    return "{JSON}";
  }

}
```

and then I have

```
public class AnotherClass {

  AClass aClass;

}
```

When I serialize `AnotherClass`, I "pretend" that method `toJson` from A`Class` is called to return the JSON view of the object.

Is there any annotation that I can use on `AClass`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using [@JsonValue](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) and [@JsonRawValue](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html) annotations. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonValue {
    public interface AClass {

        @JsonValue
        @JsonRawValue
        default String toJSON(){
            return "{\"JSON\":true}";
        }

    }

    public static class AnotherClass {
        @JsonProperty
        AClass aClass = new AClass() {};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new AnotherClass()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"aClass":{"JSON":true}}
```